# Anyone know how to disable polymer iron-autogrow-textarea input?

Tags: textarea, polymer

Can't find any info on this.

Simply trying to use 'disabled' on my iron-autogrow-textarea with no avail. Doesn't work anyway i try it, javascript or directly on element. Documentation also doesn't seem to give any insight.

Anyone have any info? Am i missing something simple?

```
 <iron-autogrow-textarea disabled style="border:none; width: 80%;" bind-value="{{bookingDetails}}"></iron-autogrow-textarea>
```

Thanks everyone,
Ryann.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

Here's the solution, i noticed there is a child textarea which i need to select directly, in my situation i used the code below. 'job_details' is the id of the autogrow-textarea.

```
    this.$.job_details.querySelector('textarea').disabled = true;
```

Thanks for checking it out.